# abort() has been called after thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++

I am making an autoclicker with a gui in which I have a thread, but whenever I try to run it it gives me an error with abort() has been called. The breakpoint is below the line where the first thread is called. I am very new to multi-threading so I don't really know what the problem is, this  is my code:

```
#include "AutoClicker.h"
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

AutoClicker::AutoClicker()
{
    std::thread loop (&AutoClicker::autoClickerMain, this);
}

AutoClicker::~AutoClicker()
{

}

void AutoClicker::setCPS(int cpsIn)
{
    delay = 1000 / cpsIn;
}

void AutoClicker::setHotkey(char hotkeyChar)
{
    hotkey = static_cast<int>(hotkeyChar);
} 

void AutoClicker::autoClickerMain()
{
    int c = 0;

    std::thread clicker(&AutoClicker::Clicker, this);

    while (1)
    {
        c = 0;
        c = _getch();
        if (c == hotkey)
        {
            running = !running;
        }
    }
}

void AutoClicker::Clicker()
{
    while (1)
    {
        if (running)
        {
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `AutoClicker::AutoClicker() { std::thread loop (&AutoClicker::autoClickerMain, this); }` creates a thread which goes out of scope and is destroyed immediately.

Comment: Why does the thread  go out of scope? And how do I fix it?

Comment: The variable `loop` is what goes out of scope. You see that right? You define it inside the constructor and then the constructor ends. You probably need a `std::thread` member variable instead.

Comment: Ohh I see now thank you so much!